# How to get deleted id in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

After deleting a row. how to get its id.

we can receive inserted ID from $this->db->insert_id(). Is there similar function for getting deleted records id.

Comment: No, you should remember this yourself. In whatever way. You could just store it as a setting, or in a session. But that is very user-specific.

Comment: first retrieve the id and then delete the record ! it would be the better way to get id......

Comment: before to delete a row save ID

Comment: I might have a great solution for this (triggers). But first, what are to trying to achieve?

Comment: you can delete a row only with ID!! so you have it!

Comment: The thing is i am deleting it with some other where columns but i wanted the deleted primary key id. No problem i made a get where to get primary key id  then i deleted the rows.

Answer (score 2):

However you will the id to delete a record.

In model, you will pass id as parameter. try below code.

```
public function delete_row($id)
{
  $this->db->where(array("id"=>$id));
  $this->db->delete("my_table");
  if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
   return $id;
  else
   return false;
}
```

**Note:** If you didn't pass id. then you have to use same parameters which are used to delete to get the record before deleting the record.

Answer (score 0):

You should first save the id you are about to delete in a variable then after passing the variable(id) to the query and the row is deleted you will be able to do whatever you want with the id that is still stored in the the variable. simple and straight forward no functions added needed.